# Why this equation is correct? (Frenet frame)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential, frenet-frame

$2(T_a-T_b)•(T'_a-T'_b)=-2T_a•T'_b-2T'_a•T_b$

Is $2T_a•T'_a=0$ ?

Please explain me why this equation work.

Comment: I edited your first equation, inserting a factor of $2$ in the $T_a' \cdot T_b$ term; your original equation was false without it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$(T_a - T_b) \cdot (T_a' - T_b')$
$= T_a \cdot (T_a' - T_b') - T_b \cdot (T_a' - T_b') = T_a \cdot T_a' - T_a \cdot T_b' - T_b \cdot T_a' + T_b \cdot T_b' \tag 1$

follows immediately from the ordinary distributive properties of the dot product $A \cdot B$ for any vectors $A$ and $B$.

If we understand $T_s$ to be the unit tangent vector field along some arc-length parametrized regular curve $\gamma(s)$ in the sense of Frenet-Serret,

$T_s = \gamma'(s), \tag 2$

then since

$T_s \cdot T_s = 1, \tag 3$

we find

$2T_s \cdot T_s' = T_s' \cdot T_s + T_s \cdot T_s' = 0 \tag 4$

holds for any value of $s$; taking $s = a$ and $s = b$, we have

$T_a \cdot T_a' = T_b \cdot T_b' = 0; \tag 5$

thus (1) becomes

$(T_a - T_b) \cdot (T_a' - T_b') =  - T_a \cdot T_b' - T_b \cdot T_a', \tag 6$

which we may multiply by $2$ to obtain

$2(T_a - T_b) \cdot (T_a' - T_b') =  2(- T_a \cdot T_b' - T_b \cdot T_a') = -2T_a \cdot T_b' - 2T_b \cdot T_a'. \tag 7$

Comment: Thank you!!! But the part, 2⋅′=0 holds for any value of s, is a little bit confusing. Is this because the derivative of a constant is zero? (⋅ = c then s⋅′s=0) So It doesn't matter if s is a non unit vector?

Comment: @loone96:  just to keep things straight, $s$ is not a vector at all, it is the (scalar) arc-length along the curve $\gamma(s)$; $T_s \cdot T_s' = 0$ holds as long as $T_s \cdot T_s$ is *any* constant; it doesn't have to be $1$.